# How to understand syntax engine in Isabelle

Tags: verification, isabelle, formal-methods

I'm attempting to understand Isabelle's inner syntax engine, but I'm having problems reading Chapter 8 of the Isabelle standard reference manual. (Isar-ref or *[The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf)* by Makarius Wenzel).

As seen in the diagram below, there is a general inner syntax engine described in the manual. I'm trying to figure out how this process works and where functions like `syntax` `translation` `print_translation` come into play in this diagram.

[image]

Furthermore, is there a simple example for learning this entire process?